# Dock developper powershell in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

On a previous Pc, I had the powershell docked at the bottom of my Visual Studio window (along with "output" or search result. However, it seems it can't do that on my current version (visual studio Professional 2019, Version 16.11.2).

From `tool > command line > developper PowerShell` I can launch a shell, but it an independent window (as if I had launched it from start menu), not a Visual Studio window that I can dock.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Package manager console it is just a PowerShell 5 windows that docks right next to the Error List and Output tabs

[Docked PowerShell Window in VS 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoNRw.png)

To open the docked PowerShell Console type Package Manager in the VS2019 Search bar

[Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2019 Search Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeCc8.png)